# Best way to update UI every minute/second?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an ObservableCollection of DateTime bind to a listbox. It shows current Time for various countries. Listbox has an itemtemplate so that i can format how the HH:MM:SS are displayed.

Now, I need to update the time for each item in ObservableCollection of DateTime every 1 second, so that the UI is also updated accordingly.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: I always prefer delegate over DispatcherTimer to do these kind of things, which is more light weight. Async calls using delegate could update the UI thread through current despatcher.

Answer (score 2):

Most advanced (and simplest) way is to use Rx extension:

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).
Subscribe(o =>
{
   // every second set current time on every item. 
   foreach(var item in YourCollection)
   {
    item.CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;
   }
});
```

and of course in item.CurrentTime setter you need to raise propertychange event.

Comment: Might want to include `ObserveOnDispatcher` to make sure the subscription executes on the UI thread. Or make sure the PropertyChange event is fired on the UI thread.